# Unix/Linux display average file size with restriction

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command

how do I display the average file size (rounded down). Use only: cat, echo, ls, wc, here is what I was able to do so far: `echo "$(cat * | wc -w; ls -l | wc -l)"` I have both of the numbers, I just can't divide them, any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by average file size ?

Comment: Try `echo $(( 25 / 5 ))`. Any ideas?

Comment: how do i do that using only: cat, echo, ls, wc

Comment: You use the shell as well: `*` expansion, pipes,`$( )` capturing and `echo` are all shell functionality, so does that mean we can use the full functionality of `bash`?

Comment: How did you come up with the requirement `Use only: cat, echo, ls, wc`? Are you sure the problem is solvable?

Comment: For an accurate average you need to check the inode number as well (`ls -li`) since `ls` gives *filenames*, and there could be more than one filename referring to the same single physical file (a *hard link*).  An associative array could be used for that, using the inode as the key and the size as the value, that will ensure uniqueness.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on codegolf.SE. Arbitrarily restricting the set of tools available is not something an actual user would do.

Comment: None of cat, echo, ls or wc can perform arithmetic.

Comment: Also, `ls` is the wrong tool for this kind of job: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it allowed to use the shell for the division?

```
$ ls -l
total 20
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  968 Dec 29  2016 bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  900 Dec 29  2016 bar.asc
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james   39 Dec 29  2016 compr.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 1056 Dec 28  2016 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james  896 Dec 29  2016 foo.asc
$ cat * | wc -c
3859
$ ls | wc -l
5
$ echo $(( $(cat * | wc -c) / $(ls | wc -l) ))      # solution part
771
$ echo 5*771 | bc 
3855
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
n=( * ); s=( $(ls -sk) ); echo $(( ${s[1]} / ${#n[@]} ))
```

use an array to count the number of files in the directory and `ls` to get the total size in Kbytes, then print the result of the quotient.

Comment: With some versions of `ls` (from GNU coreutils) option `-k` is ignored (bug).

Comment: Use only: cat, echo, ls, wc

Comment: @alphaQ don't know what you mean, this is using only `ls` and `echo` (which is a builtin in bash). Compared with the accepted answer that spawns 4 processes this is much more efficient with only 1.