# How to calculate the total size of all files from ls- l by using cut, eval, head, tr, tail, ls and echo

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
 ls -l | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f5
```

I tried above code and got following output.

> 158416
>   757249
>   574994
>   144436
>   520739
>   210444
>   398630
>   1219080
>   256965
>   684782
>   393445
>   157957
>   273642
>   178980
>   339245

How to add these numbers. I'm stuck here. Please no use of awk, perl, shell scripting etc.

Comment: What is the point of restricting yourself to those tools? Is this some kind of puzzle?

Comment: See: [Unix/Linux display average file size with restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52565341/3776858)

Comment: @oguzismail or some kind of homework assignment. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/52565341/1255289

Comment: If you aim to avoid all forms of programming, then this question is off topic for StackOverflow. Try [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to use `du`. Somethings like:

```
du -h -a -c | tail -n1
```

Will give you the sum total. You can also use the `-d` argument to specify how deep the traversing should go like:

```
du -d 1 -h -a -c | tail -n1
```

**You will have to clarify what you mean by "no use of shell scripting" for anyone to come up with a more meaningful answer.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way but $((...)) is shell scripting

```
eval echo $(( $(ls -l | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f5 | tr '\n' '+')  0 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  It's not meant for parsing.  Use `du` as with [*Martin Gergov*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52568947/6136214).  Or [`du` and `find`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134245/total-size-of-group-of-files-selected-with-find), or [just `du`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41551/165517).

But if just adding numbers is the sole focus, (even if the input is iffy), here's the laziest possible method (first install [**num-utils**](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/)):

```
ls -l | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f5 | numsum
```

And there's other ways, see also: [How can I quickly sum all numbers in a file?](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/)